# pandas groupby sums differences between two columns and get the average for each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following `df`,

```
year    code    col1   col2
2019    1       2      3
2019    1       3      5
2019    1       2      4
2018    2       1      4
2018    2       2      6
```

I want to `groupby` `df` by `year` and `code`, then sum the differences between `col2` and `col1`, and then averages the sum over the group size;

```
df.apply(lambda row: (row['col_2'] - row['col_1']).mean(level=[0, 1]).reset_index(name='avg_num')
```

this code seems to calculate the mean of differences rather than summing the differences and divided by the group size, so how to fix this?

```
year    code    col1   col2    avg_num
2019    1       2      3       1.66
2019    1       3      5       1.66
2019    1       2      4       1.66
2018    2       1      4       3.5
2018    2       2      6       3.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column filled by aggregate values:

```
df['avg_num'] = (df.assign(avg_num=df.col2 - df.col1)
                   .groupby(['year', 'code'])['avg_num']
                   .transform('mean').round(2))
print (df)
   year  code  col1  col2  avg_num
0  2019     1     2     3     1.67
1  2019     1     3     5     1.67
2  2019     1     2     4     1.67
3  2018     2     1     4     3.50
4  2018     2     2     6     3.50
```

Another solution without `assign`, but necessary pass columns to `groupby` like `df['year']` and `df['code']`:

```
df['avg_num'] = ((df['col2'] - df['col1']).groupby([df['year'], df['code']])
                                          .transform('mean').round(2))
print (df)
   year  code  col1  col2  avg_num
0  2019     1     2     3     1.67
1  2019     1     3     5     1.67
2  2019     1     2     4     1.67
3  2018     2     1     4     3.50
4  2018     2     2     6     3.50
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create an intermediate table to hold the aggregated values and then join it back to the original DataFrame.

```
aggs = df.assign(avg_num=df.col2 - df.col1) \
         .groupby(['year', 'code'], as_index=False)['avg_num'].mean().round(2)

print(aggs)

   year  code  avg_num
0  2018     2   3.50
1  2019     1   1.67

df.merge(aggs, how='inner', left_on=['year', 'code'], right_on=['year', 'code'])

   year  code  col1  col2  avg_num
0  2019     1     2     3   1.67
1  2019     1     3     5   1.67
2  2019     1     2     4   1.67
3  2018     2     1     4   3.50
4  2018     2     2     6   3.50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = df.groupby(['year','code']).apply(lambda x: sum(list(abs(x.col2 - x.col1))) / len(list(abs(x.col2 - x.col1)))).reset_index().rename({0:'avg_num'},axis=1)

df.merge(data, on='year').drop('code_y', axis=1).rename({'code_x':'code'}, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   year  code  col1  col2   avg_num
0  2019     1     2     3  1.666667
1  2019     1     3     5  1.666667
2  2019     1     2     4  1.666667
3  2018     2     1     4  3.500000
4  2018     2     2     6  3.500000
```